# bob.math is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Hope you can help me.

So recently I make a project with python, and is required some libraries. One of the is bob, the documentation only have instruction for conda, but I dont want to use that, because I have pip installed. 
The problem is when I install **bob.bio.gmm** this error occured

```
Collecting bob.learn.linear (from bob.bio.gmm==2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/70/38c1736d20fca8ad5af07fc7eee703aad7ec9a399ba08189548c83b6f5c3/bob.learn.linear-2.1.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-swf4ev3q/bob.learn.linear/setup.py", line 50, in <module>
        boost_modules = boost_modules,
      File "/run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bob/blitz/extension.py", line 52, in __init__
        BobExtension.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
        bob_includes, bob_libraries, bob_library_dirs, bob_macros = get_bob_libraries(self.bob_packages)
      File "/run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 206, in get_bob_libraries
        pkg = importlib.import_module(package)
      File "/run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bob/math/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        bob.extension.load_bob_library('bob.math', __file__)
      File "/run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 257, in load_bob_library
        ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(full_libname)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
            return self._dlltype(name)
          File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
            self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
        OSError: /run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bob/math/libbob_math.so: undefined symbol: dpotrf_

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-swf4ev3q/bob.learn.linear/
```

So, any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: Old OpenBLAS? Run `ldd /run/media/juunnn/EXOrdium/VID/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bob/math/libbob_math.so | grep -I libopenblas`, what version does the lib have?

Comment: libopenblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.3 (0x00007efd5aed4000)

Comment: Hmm, the exact lib version is still unclear - can you check if `/usr/include/openblas_config.h` or `/usr/local/include/openblas_config.h` exists and issue `grep OPENBLAS_VERSION openblas_config.h`? Or if you're on Ubuntu, check the output of `apt search openblas`.